# Git gives me 'Permission Denied' when I use git add 'sampleFile.txt'

Tags: github, gitlab, git-bash

```
fatal: Unable to create 'C:/Program Files/Git/My Sample/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
```

If I add 'git add 'myFile.txt'' in Git Bash it shows the above error though other files are not using the directory.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't create a repo where `git bash` open: in its session, '/' is by default where Git is installed `C:/Program Files/Git/`

Open a git bash in one of your C:\Users\you... folder, and try a `git init NewRepo` there.